# How to show progress bar in percentage JQuery,HTML and CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css, progress-bar

I have created progress bar in JQuery that should display line with the progress. Current code only shows the value in percentage. I would like to see my progress bar to start from 0% and go up to 100%. Also I want my value to be in the center of the progress bar. Here is my current code:

```
xhr: function(){
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
        if(evt.lengthComputable){
            var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
            percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
            $('.progress').text(percentComplete + '%');

            if(percentComplete === 100){
                $('.progress').addClass('hide');
                console.log("Successfully uploaded!");
            }
        }
    },false);
    xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
        if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
            console.log(percentComplete);
            $('.progress').text(percentComplete + '%');
        }
    }, false);
    return xhr;
}

HTML:

    <div class="progress"></div>

CSS:

    .progress {
        margin-top: 10px;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        width: 300px;
        height: 20px;
        background: #a3bfcc;
        transition: width .3s;
    }
    .progress.hide {
        opacity: 0;
        transition: opacity 1.3s;
    }
```

Also I'm not sure if my JQuery part should have to Listeners or just one. If anyone can help with this problem please let me know.

Comment: You can use jqueryUI progress bar : https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Comment: @MathieuDormeval I seen this before but I wasn't sure if I can implement that code in my function. Can you provide any example for my code above? Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at : https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#label and click on viewsource, you have an example of source code.

Answer (score 5):

You could use the html5 progress element

```
<progress max = "100" value = "50"></progress>
```

That will give you a 50% full progress bar, this can be easily styled and animated using css & javascript.

Read more here:
https://css-tricks.com/html5-progress-element/

Comment: What should I use to link the progress tag in HTML and value from JQuery? Div around or place the id on the progress tag?

Comment: you could change the attribute value with JQuery: `$('.progress').attr('value',50);` and add class of progress to the progress element

Comment: Replace the value 50 with the value from the JQuery?

Comment: exactly. what every your value is (0 - 100) will be added through JQuery

Comment: Something like this $('progress').attr('value'); ?

Comment: `<progess class = 'progress-bar' max = '100' value  = '50'></progress>` and then in your JQuery  ' $('.progress-bar').attr('value',50); '  using the class name as the selector

Comment: Is it possible to place the actual number with the percentage symbol inside of the bar?

Comment: with some css yes that wouldn't be a problem. simply position a div over the progress bar

Answer (score 1):

You can try [ShieldUI](http://www.shieldui.com) 's [progressbar](https://demos.shieldui.com/web/progressbar/basic-usage). Its easy to implement and provides a lot of properities.